# How should I solve this?

Tags: python-3.x

Given two cells of a chessboard. If they are painted in one color, print the word YES, and if in a different color - NO.
The program receives the input of four numbers from 1 to 8, each specifying the column and row number, first two - for the first cell, and then the last two - for the second cell.

Comment: Hello and Welcome! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: The problem statement in its current state is confusing and unclear what the problem is. "Given two cells of a chessboard" -- why two cells, what is the significance of only two cells? "If they are painted in one color" -- what is the significance of two cells painted in one color? "print YES if they are painted in one color, NO if different color" -- what does this mean? The last sentence seems unrelated. Are you wanting to move a chess piece from one cell to another cell?

Comment: https://snakify.org/lessons/if_then_else_conditions/problems/chess_board/       I am really stuck here. and not able to solve it . And I am sorry I am not a active member of stackoverflow and also new to programming.